# Are still this code vulnerable to (Invalid File Uploading Attack) such as image that contains PHP code?

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, code-injection

Providing user to upload images has wide usage, however, checking file extension and MIME type not guarantee correct file type.

Alternative:
I used `imagejpeg()` and `imagecreatefromjpeg()` functions for creating the image from `$_FILE['userfile']['tmp_name']` and then saving it in `images/` dir. In this case, I ignored `move_uploaded_file()` function.

### Are still this code vulnerable to fake image uploading attack?

```
$filename = $_FILE['inputfile']['name'];
$upload_path = 'images/';
//extract extension
$ext = strtolower(substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1));

// return mime type ala mimetype extension
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
//get MIME type of the given file
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
//close finfo
finfo_close($finfo);

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    //first check: file extension and mime type
    if(!in_array($ext, array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png')) && !in_array($mime, array('image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png')) ){
     die("Error1: Invalid Image type");
    }
    if($ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg'){
       $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILE['inputfile']['tmp_name']);
       if($im){

        $createimage = imagejpeg($im, $upload_path.$_FILE['inputfile']['name']);
        if(!$createimage){
          die("Error3: Can't create image!");
        }
        //last check
        $filecontent = file_get_contents($upload_path.$_FILE['inputfile']['name']);

        //clean the file from any php code
        $filecontent = str_replace(array("<?php", "<?", "?>"), "", $filecontent);

        $handle = fopen($upload_path.$_FILE['inputfile']['name'], "wb");
        fwrite($handle, $filecontent);
        fclose($handle);
       }
       else{

        die("Error2: Invalid Image Detected");

       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Really if all you are worried about is PHP code being executed, making sure to save the file where it is NOT a PHP extension is all that is needed to prevent PHP code from being executed on server. That way PHP code or not the server will not treat the file as PHP since it is not `.php`

Comment: how if I want to crop the image? this produces system error in another process.

Comment: That is a completely different question than the one being asked. Please open a new question for that.

Comment: @crypticツ: Saving image in server will be just for simple view or resizing at least, then, if you allow uploading fake image its not good.

Comment: One common method is to run the image through [@getimageize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) if it returns error it is not an image. Then you discard the image. You should Google what you are trying to do, there is plenty of information available to detect if an image is valid or not.

Comment: Depending on the PHP version, it might still be possible as not all file system functions were not null-byte safe until PHP 5.3.4 (see [#60985](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60985)).

Comment: just define what image extension want to upload and do not check what should not be uploaded. just create an array for jpg, jpeg, png, bmp and check only for these extensions thats all

Comment: @ManojGarwa: extension is nothing!

Answer (score 1):

One can always embed PHP code safely in a perfectly valid image file. There are too many ways to do that to worth even thinking avoiding them. Many valid image formats, many data containers such as EXIF in jpg for example, pixel level and compression manipulation, etc.

To be on the safe side one should protect the server from arbitrary file inclusion attacks and sanitize the file extensions to escape from apache configuration mistakes.

A more crazy approach is to create a slightly modified copy of the image, more exactly create a new image from the original one modified, a slight resize or color manipulation will delete the bitmap level PHP injections while copying will save you from most of the PHP injected in other data containers within the image.